# C, MPI: Program not terminating and not printing numbers

Tags: c, mpi

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){ 
    int numtasks, rank, rc, count, tag=1, i =0;
    MPI_Status Stat;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0)  //for process 0 we print received messages
    { 

        for(i=0; i< 9; i ++){   
            printf("value of i is: %d\n",i );
            rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
            printf("Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with tag %d \n", rank, count, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);
        }
    }
    else //for the other 9 processes
    { 
        if(rank % 2 == 0){  //if rank is an even number
            rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    //send message to process with rank 0
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
} 
//
```

This program is run with 10 processes. Process with rank 0 receives messages and prints them out if the source process has an even numbered rank. Processes with rank other than 0 send process with rank 0 a message containing a character 'x'
Now, in regards to rank 0, it has a for loop that basically loops 9 times. In the loop it prints out the value of the iterating variable i, and the received character and source process.
However, when I run my program it does not terminate.
The output looks like this:

```
Task 0: Received 0 char(s) from task 2 with tag 1 
value of i is: 1
Task 0: Received 0 char(s) from task 6 with tag 1 
value of i is: 2
Task 0: Received 0 char(s) from task 4 with tag 1 
value of i is: 3
Task 0: Received 0 char(s) from task 8 with tag 1 
value of i is: 4
```

How do I get it to print the other values of `i` such as 5,6,7,8,9?

Answer (score 3):

You're using a master-slave architecture for parallel processing, your process 0 is the master and is waiting for the input of 9 other process, but in your code only process with even id number will fire an output, namely process 2, 4, 6, 8.

you didn't put behavior for process 1,3,5,7 and 9 so the master is still waiting for them hence, the program waiting for parallel process to finish:

you need to complete your source code here

```
    if(rank % 2 == 0){  //if rank is an even number
            rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    //send message to process with rank 0
        }else{
           //logic for process 1,3,5,7,9
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, is it possible to do my program using MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv instead since they are non-blocking? Like, I don't want my program to halt. Even if I haven't received a message just skip over it and end the program?

Comment: Well, i don't think non-blocking call will solve your problem because your program will still be waiting, i think the best is to either terminate your MPI program when you have all the value you're looking for with MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD) for example or to launch & receive the exact number of process you need, in your case 4 instead of 9

Comment: If you are willing to "end the program even if a message is not received", then why to you even try to receive it in the first place ?