# C, MPI: Program won't display correct output

Tags: c, mpi

I have an MPI program that can use 2, 3, 14, 61, .... X number of processes.
Out of these processes, processes that are ranked with an odd number send messages, whereas the process with rank 0 receives messages and displays them.
However, my program displays only 1 message when it is run with say 15 or 64 processes.
This is my code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int rank, i =0;
    int sendMsg = 123;
    int recvMsg = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int count;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Request request;
    int errs = 0;
    double start = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Init( 0, 0 );

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if(rank == 0)
    {
        while(!flag)
        {
            MPI_Iprobe( MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &status );

        }

        MPI_Recv( &recvMsg, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );

        printf("Received message from process %d\n",status.MPI_SOURCE);

    }
    else{
        if(rank % 2 != 0){
            printf("Sent from process: %d\n",rank );
            MPI_Isend( &sendMsg, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request );
            MPI_Wait( &request, &status );
        }

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return errs;
}
```

This is my output:

```
Sent from process: 1
Sent from process: 5
Sent from process: 3
Sent from process: 7
Received message from process 3
```

As you can see I expected the output to also say that It received messages from processes 1,5, and 7.
How can I achieve my goal? My program should also terminate. Thank you

How to run the code in the terminal:

```
mpicc main.c -o main -Wall  
mpirun -np X main
```

Where X is an integer greater than or equal to 2

Comment: First, you can get rid of `MPI_Iprobe()`, and simply `MPI_Send()`.. Then if you run with `size` MPI tasks, you need to `MPI_Recv()` `size/2` messages.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "you need to MPI_Recv() size/2 messages"

Comment: I'm using MPI_Probe because I may or may not receive a message

Comment: there are `size/2` odd ranks that `MPI_Send()` to rank `0`, so rank `0` has to expect `size/2` messages, and hence call `MPI_Recv()` `size/2` times. Makes sense ? What do you mean by "may or may not receive a message" ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that suppose I send 5 messages, and my MPI_Recv sits in a loop that iterates 10 times. I want to be able to receive those 5 messages AND exit the loop. I dont want to stay in the loop waiting forever for the 6th message to be recieved

Comment: The number of messages I send can vary and I may not know how many are sent

Comment: Your last comment is in direct conflict with the fully deterministic code you provided. It is also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658843/c-mpi-program-not-terminating-and-not-printing-numbers you previously asked, and this is very bad practice on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C, MPI: Program not terminating and not printing numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658843/c-mpi-program-not-terminating-and-not-printing-numbers)